# Click through multiple rows on a webpage in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I have run into an issue trying to retrieve data from a table on the surface of a web page. In each row of the table there is a link that leads to more details about the information in each row. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzBfi.png) The automation needs to decide whether or not to copy the row information based on criteria that is only given within the link.

Part of where I'm stuck is due to the fact that the number of rows in the table can vary, so I can't just specify each link as it's own element. So I need my bot to:

1. Start at the first row of information
2. Click the details link
3. Decide whether or not the information from the correlating row is needed
4. Go back to the place where the table is and copy down info if needed
5. Go to the next row and repeat steps 1-4 for the rest of the table

I believe I have a handle on step 3 and 4, along with 2 if clicking an element doesn't change with iterating through the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a loop, that will iterate it self every time whenever you will go back to the table after copy info from the row.

So I would do something like that:

1.Click the details link

2.Decide whether or not the information from the correlating row is needed

3.Go back to the place where the table is and copy down info if needed

4.Go to the next row and repeat steps 1-4 for the rest of the table

5.Check if there is a next row. Yes? Loop to step 1. No? End.